# C++98 string concatenation with c_str() return

Tags: c++, string, c++98

I wanted to create a custom exception by concatonating a string before returning it on what(). I am aware of other ways to achive the wanted result, i just want to undertand why the 3 following pieces of code are behaving differently.

```
class InvalidFormat : public std::exception
{
    private:
        std::string _exceptionValue;
    public:
        InvalidFormat(std::string str);
        const char *what() const throw();
};
```

```
InvalidFormat::InvalidFormat(std::string str) : _exceptionValue(str) {}

const char *InvalidFormat::what() const throw() {
return ("Format is invalid => " + _exceptionValue).c_str();}
//doesn't output anything
```

```
InvalidFormat::InvalidFormat(std::string str) : _exceptionValue(str) {}

const char *InvalidFormat::what() const throw() {
return std::string("Format is invalid => ").assign(_exceptionValue).c_str();}
//outputs random data
```

```
InvalidFormat::InvalidFormat(std::string str) : _exceptionValue("Format is invalid => " + str) {}

const char *InvalidFormat::what() const throw() {
return _exceptionValue.c_str();}
//outputs is correct
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local (temporary) variable.

Comment: Take a look at what [c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) actually does. It returns a pointer to the underlying storage of the `std::string` object. If the `std::string` is destroyed, you're left with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following calls `c_str()` on a temporary `std::string` whose life ends after the full expression (at the  `;`):

```
return ("Format is invalid => " + _exceptionValue).c_str(); // UB-prone
```

When `InvalidFormat::what()` returns, the returned pointer points to memory freed and gone, which is undefined behaviour. This is no better:

```
return std::string("Format is invalid => ").assign(_exceptionValue).c_str(); // UB-prone
```

---

You must store the result of the concatenation if you want to return a non-owning pointer to it:

```
InvalidFormat::InvalidFormat(std::string str)
    : _exceptionValue("Format is invalid => " + str)
{}

const char *InvalidFormat::what() const throw()
{
    return _exceptionValue.c_str(); // OK
}
```

Comment: Also, it avoids exception being raised in your exception handling code ;)

Comment: We need a phrase for that, like exception inception. A while back we had a crash handler that wrote a minidump and log of the crash then uploaded it offsite for analysis. Worked great until one day there was a bug that filled the hard drives of several servers with thousands of dumps and flooded our internet connection making it very difficult to stop remotely. Good times! :)

Comment: sorry for late edit. It took me a while to understand, but i get it now. Thank you